# Can't rearrange Mission Control spaces

Tags: macos, mission-control

I can't rearrange full screen spaces in mission control.  When I drag one to move it, it never seems to stick back onto the mission control bar.  If I drop the space on the bar the animation shows it going back to the dock and it disappears from the mission control bar.  I can drag the space from the bar to the desktop.

It tends to leave behind a semi transparent image of the full screen view (similar to the one that can be dragged around in mission control) and this persists even after mission control is closed.  The only way to get rid of it is to restart my machine.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have seen this issue on my machine as well and am yet to find a solution. Will post here if I find a solution.

Comment: This is a problem I am also experiencing. If I find a solution, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Just to reconfirm that I understand it correct, the issue is:

On trying to move full-screen apps between two spaces by going into spaces (press F3 button or 3-finger swipe above), it (full-screen app) just slips to one the desktops and doesn't get accommodated like desktops (space is created automatically by the GUI for insertion and you can drop the desktop there).

Have found the following:

1. Generally restarting the Mac solves this issue for some time (few days) but then it returns again.
2. Once the full screen app drops into one of the desktops, pick it and insert it where you want in the top spaces panel.

This is not exactly a solution but a workaround or change of habit if you don't want to restart your mac for something so trivial.

Hope this helps in reducing the inconvenience.